# Lilypond: How to insert a white space to shorten the last line?

Tags: sheet-music, lilypond

[image]

I'd like to have the result as in the image. Is there a specific method to have that white space after the bar?

Comment: What do you mean by 'white space' exactly? Really an empty staff, as in the picture, or actually a blank space (ragged-last)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding in a [spacer rest](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/writing-rests#invisible-rests) (`s`) after the final bar line?

Spacer rests are invisible, but take up a space with the value of the corresponding note specified by a number (just like a regular note or rest).

Something like: `... \bar "|." s1`

You might need to adjust the number value, or use a couple of them to get as much space as in your picture.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to achieve this is to use ragged-last to tell Lilypond not to space out the last line and overriding the width of the note lines to the actual line width.

Using spacer rests will kind of force the amount of tail space, which is not really optimal.

So do this:

```
{ c' d' e' f' \bar "|." }
{ c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c'' \bar "|." }
{ c' d' e' f' g' a' b' c'' d'' e'' f'' g'' \bar "|." }

\paper {
  ragged-last = ##t
}

\layout {
  \override Staff.StaffSymbol.width =
  #(lambda (grob)
     (ly:output-def-lookup (ly:grob-layout grob) 'line-width))
}
```

resulting in
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
\layout {
    ragged-last = ##t
}
```

According to the [docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/notation/line-width), the last line will then simply take its natural horizontal length.

That means that, unlike the score shown in the question, the staff lines will end at the final barline, leaving only blank space to the right. If you want the staff lines to continue, it's probably better to use [spacer rests](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/writing-rests#invisible-rests), as per another answer.